# Not able to access Function in .then in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Can you please help me to understand why i am getting the error the below error and how i can resolve the same. What i want to do is to navigate to the URL which i am getting from my Apex class.

Error

```
TypeError: this.navigateToWebPage is not a function
```

My JS code

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getAgreementId from '@salesforce/apex/AdobeSignLwcHandler.getAgreementId';
import getsigningUrl from '@salesforce/apex/AdobeSignLwcHandler.getsigningUrl';
const DELAY = 7000;
export default class ESignButton extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
   
    @api recordId;
    templateId = 'a1a4c0000001h0JAAQ';
    aggreementId;
    signUrl;

    handleEsign(){
        getAgreementId({masterId: this.recordId,templateId: this.templateId})
        .then((result)=>{
            this.aggreementId = result;
            let apexAgrmtId = result;
            console.log('This is the aggrementId ',this.aggreementId);
            if(this.aggreementId !== null){
                setTimeout(this.crSigningUrl,DELAY,this.aggreementId);
                //this.crSigningUrl(this.aggreementId);
            }

        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

    crSigningUrl(apexAgrmtId){
        getsigningUrl({AgrmtId : apexAgrmtId})
        .then((result)=>{
         console.log('this is the result',result);
          let apexResult = result;
          console.log('this is the Apex result',apexResult);
          console.log(typeof(apexResult));
          this.navigateToWebPage(apexResult);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
        
    }

    navigateToWebPage(adobeSignUrl) {
        console.log('This is the navigation Url ',adobeSignUrl);
        console.log('Type of Url', typeof(adobeSignUrl));
       
    } 

}
```

My LWC HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Proceed E-Sign" onclick={handleEsign}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class AdobeSignLwcHandler {
    public string sigingUrl;
    public static Id AgrId;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getAgreementId(String masterId, String templateId){
        System.debug('This is the account Id '+masterId);
        System.debug('This is the template Id '+templateId);
        Map<String,echosign_dev1.AgreementTemplateVariable> agreementTemplateVariables = new Map<String,echosign_dev1.AgreementTemplateVariable>();
        agreementTemplateVariables.put('userEmail',new echosign_dev1.AgreementTemplateVariable('userEmail','akhosla@innomar-strategies.com'));
        AgrId = echosign_dev1.AgreementTemplateService.load(templateId,masterId,agreementTemplateVariables);
        System.debug(AgrId);
        return AgrId;

    }

    //@future(callout=true)
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string getsigningUrl(string AgrmtId){
        System.debug('Agreement Id received from Js '+AgrmtId);
        Id AgrId = Id.valueOf(AgrmtId);
        System.debug('Agreement Id pass to API '+AgrId);
        String currentAggreementUrl;
        List<echosign_dev1.EchoSignApiService.SigningUrl> signURL = echosign_dev1.EchoSignApiService.getSigningUrls(AgrId);
        currentAggreementUrl = String.valueOf(signURL[0].esignUrl);
        System.debug(currentAggreementUrl);
        return currentAggreementUrl;

    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string currentSigningUrl(String signUrl){
       return signUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem with this is that the callback function is bound to "window" (meaning that "this" is the window object when the function is invoked).

The easiest way to resolve this is to change the call to setTimeout to:

```
setTimeout(() => {this.crSigningUrl(this.agreementId)}, DELAY);
```

The use of an arrow function avoids the change in binding for `this`.

That said, I am not sure why you feel it necessary to delay the call to this function nor why you feel the function needs to take a parameter already accessible from the `this` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment why I am using Delay function is beacuse the API service which i am calling has some dependency on the first function and first function has a future method. These all are managed pack and adobe.

Answer (score 1):

bind 'this' context .

Alternatively if you want to go synchronous you can use async await feature .

```
  functionName = async () => {
    try {
        let result = await serverCall();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
}
```